# getting demographic information about twitter user

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, rest, twitter

i am creating twitter App in C# in which i will write username and all his demographic data will be shown.I had the twitter [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) but couldn't got any solution.Any one who can assist me in doing  this.Thanks

Comment: This would only be possible if this information published by the Twitter API.  **What have you tried?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can get user information with LINQ to Twitter:

```
        var users =
            from tweet in twitterCtx.User
            where tweet.Type == UserType.Show &&
                  tweet.ScreenName == "JoeMayo"
            select tweet;

        var user = users.SingleOrDefault();

        var name = user.Name;
        var lastStatus = user.Status == null ? "No Status" : user.Status.Text;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Last Tweet: {1}\n", name, lastStatus);
```

More information here: http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Querying%20User%20Info&referringTitle=Getting%20User%20Information.